# Packet modification for interception and redirection

Tags: windows, packets

I have been trying to find some way of redirecting outbound TCP packets under windows.

from from : https://github.com/basil00/Divert/blob/master/doc/windivert.html

"The WinDivert driver is automatically (and silently) installed on demand whenever 
your application calls WinDivertOpen(). The calling application must have Administrator privileges."

Am a newbie in windows service programming. I want my Windows service to call the function WinDivertOpen().

Can someone just give a lead  sample on how to go about it.

Thanks

Comment: Then call `WinDivertOpen()`.

Comment: @ CodeCaster  ..thank  you for the comment, but  how in a typical windows service ...I need a code snippet

Comment: There is no "typical Windows Service". Start by tagging with the appropriate programming language.